# Attributes that control cmdlet's Definition

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, pssnapin

I am creating a number of Powershell cmdlet's and am noticing that after I install my snap-in and execute the following command the parameter data types are listed as single instead of the types programmed (in my case float).

```
get-command -pssnapin myPSSnapin | format-list definition

Definition : Get-Value -Param1<Single> -Param2<Single>
```

Does anyone know where do I control these values since it is not automatically selecting the proper type?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Single` and `System.Double` are the .NET framework names for floating point types.  C# `float` and `double` map to them just like `int` and `long` map to `System.Int32` and `System.Int64`.

Comment: So i guess you can't control that other that what it is doing.